# javascript value not adding

Tags: javascript, function, variables, onchange

```
<html>

    <head></head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function total() {
            if (document.form.t1.value == cash) {
                var onet = document.form.one.value
            } else {
                var onet = 0;
            }
            if (document.form.t2.value == cash) {
                var twot = document.form.two.value
            } else {
                var twot = 0;
            }
            if (document.form.t3.value == cash) {
                var threet = document.form.three.value
            } else {
                var threet = 0;
            }
            document.form.sum.value = parseFloat(onet) + parseFloat(twot) + parseFloat(threet);
        }
    </script>

    <body>
        <form name="form">
            <ol>
                <li>Amount :
                    <input type="text" name="one" onchange="total()" />Type :
                    <select name="t1" onchange="total()">
                        <option value="cash">cash</option>
                        <option value="cheque">cheque</option>
                    </select>
                    <br/>
                </li>
                <li>Amount :
                    <input type="text" name="two" onchange="total()" />Type :
                    <select name="t2" onchange="total()">
                        <option value="cash">cash</option>
                        <option value="cheque">cheque</option>
                    </select>
                    <br/>
                </li>
                <li>Amount :
                    <input type="text" name="three" onchange="total()" />Type :
                    <select name="t3" onchange="total()">
                        <option value="cash">cash</option>
                        <option value="cheque">cheque</option>
                    </select>
                    <br/>
                </li>
            </ol>Total :
            <input type="text" name="sum" />
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

In the above code what i am trying to do is: If from the option a user selects cash and then goes to the next field it will be auto added to the sum, if cheque is selected then its value will be zero or it will be not added. So if a user selects two vcash and one cheque then the row with the option cash will be added and the result will be the sum of them but there no value is coming, it will show blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Krisku, that you need to use a string instead of a undefined variable.

or else you can add

```
  var cash = "cash";
```

Still you will have wrong result as "NaN". because the other field variables are no defined yet when the first field value is changed.

So, do like this for getting the result:

```
    document.form.sum.value = parseFloat(onet) || 0 + parseFloat(twot) || 0 + parseFloat(threet) || 0;
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fuBSw/1/)

The above code make sure that you are adding a number(*atleast 0*) instead of something else like undefined or null.

Comment: after the first row the code does not work i.e the 2nd row and third row is not getting added to the sum but when I use the below code it works perfectly


`document.form.sum.value = (parseFloat(onet) || 0) + (parseFloat(twot) || 0) + (parseFloat(threet) || 0);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around the name "cash" in the following expressions:

```
if (document.form.t1.value=="cash"){
```

otherwise you try to compare against an undefined variable and the test will fail.